# Lazy load application theme styles with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I am trying to switch the `href` of a `<link />` for theming purposes and the SCSS themes live in a packages folder of my monorepo that are symlinked in `node_modules`. I need to be able to compile and reference these.

I came across the following fixed issue: [angular/angular-cli#3401](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3401) and have been trying to implement something similar:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    {
        "input": "../node_modules/@org/themes/dark.scss",
        "output": "dark",
        "lazy": true
    }
],
```

My understanding (perhaps incorrect) was that this would compile the `dark.scss` file into `dist/dark.bundle.css` and that I would be able to load it via http://localhost:4200/dist/dark.bundle.css but it is not working as expected. Am I misunderstanding something or doing this completely wrong?

How do I compile an SCSS file from `node_modules` that I can then lazy load in the app? Is there another/better approach I could try instead?

**Additional notes:**

- Using Angular version `4.2.4`
- Using Angular CLI version `1.3.0`
- The [documentation for this approach](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/global-styles.md)
- I am working in a monorepo so `node_modules/@org/themes` is a symlink
- I have tried using `ng serve --preserve-symlinks` option in case the above was the issue. It made no difference

I have looked into the way that the [Angular Material docs website approaches this problem](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/package.json#L13) and it seems they have a custom build script that compiles the SCSS files to CSS files in the `assets` directory before serving the application. I thought the fixed issue above removed the need for this step but perhaps not. Is this the only way it can be done?

## SOLVED

Thanks to @Kuncevic. I was missing the `--extract-css` flag.

Working config:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    {
        "input": "../node_modules/@org/themes/src/dark.scss",
        "output": "themes/dark",
        "lazy": true
    }
],
```

And with the following serve script, I can access it via http://localhost:4200/themes/dark.bundle.css:

`ng serve --extract-css --preserve-symlinks`

Comment: I was missing to add '.bundle.css' extension that Angular appends automatically

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot...I was not aware of the "lazy" flag.

Comment: "lazy" keyword has been replaced with "inject" in the latest version.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By setting `"lazy": true` means it won't appear in `index.html` but there is no mechanism that will lazy load that bundle for you, check that [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6018#issuecomment-295953509):

> The lazy option doesn't actually lazy load anything. It just prevents
>   it from being executed on application startup.

I agree `"lazy": true` is a bit confusing at first.

If you run `ng build` you can actually see what's gets outputed in your build and analyze all the files produced by cli.

When you do:

```
{
    "input": "../node_modules/@org/themes/dark.scss",
    "output": "dark",
    "lazy": true
}
```

You should be able to access your file directly at http://localhost:4200/dark.bundle.js but it wont appear in `index.html` as you set `"lazy": true`

> If you want to get `dark.bundle.css` bundle instead of
>   `dark.bundle.js` in dev mode you can use `--extract-css` flag.

The reason why cli generating styles in to `js` bundle in dev mode is because this way is much quicker. Bud when you do prod build like `ng buld --prod` it will output in to `.css` by default anyway.

Comment: I removed the bullet about `lazy: true` from my question because it seems that has confused things. I understand how it works but when using it, I can't seem to lazily access my generated CSS file directly. This is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @jjenzz you can, try http://localhost:4200/dark.bundle.js, to make sure it is there run `ng build` and check the `dist` folder.

Comment: A `dark.bundle.js` file is generated but that's not what I need. The issue is that I want to be able to access a `dark.bundle.css` file.

Comment: @jjenzz by default there is no `dark.bundle.css` the `dark.bundle.js` contains all your `dark.scss` styles.

Comment: I know, that's what I said in my OP (before I removed the `lazy` bullet). My question is whether it is possible to get access to the generated `.css` file using this configuration. I have commented on my OP though saying that it is looking more and more like it is not possible and that I will need to follow Angular Material's approach of manually compiling the `scss` files into the `assets` directory before serving the project.

Comment: @jjenzz OK, try to play with a flag `--extract-css`, that should give you css bundle.

Comment: Just wanted to add that CSS lazy styles will still get a hash (like `lazy-style.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css`) on prod builds, which can make lazy loading them hard since you don't know the hash in advance.

To prevent this, use the `--output-hashing=media` flag on prod builds. Now you will get `lazy-style.bundle.css` instead.

Comment: @FilipeSilva Ah of course. Hmmm, we wouldn't really want to remove the hash from everything though, just the themes. I guess this is why Angular Material has it's own build script.

Comment: Yeah it's a limitation currently, haven't yet found a good way of not adding the hash to the lazy bundles only.

Comment: Thanks @Kuncevic. This helped me to access my CSS style independently through JS and prevent it from loading on its own.

Comment: In newer versions it's called "inject"

Comment: To confirm @JohnWhite, here are the docs: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#styles-and-scripts-configuration

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old post, but I have not found a full example just fragments to implement lazy loading in Angular for *CSS files* or *js files*. This is a solution with Angular 7.1.4 version and lazy loading of **font-awesome 4.7** and **bootstrap 4**

1. Install bootstrap and font-awesome

```
    npm install --save font-awesome bootstrap
```

2. Edit your **angular.json** file to make sure that the compiler will generate separated files into the **dist** folder

   ```
      "styles": [
         "src/styles.css",
         {
           "input": "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
           "lazy": true,
           "bundleName": "font-awesome"
         },
         {
           "input": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
           "lazy": true,
           "bundleName": "bootstrap"
         }
       ],
   ```

   Parameter explanations:

*"input"* : "the location where the command from the 1st step will download bootstrap and font-awesome"

*"lazy"* : "the value of **true** will make sure that the compiler will not embed the *bootstrap.min.css* and *font-awesome.css* files into the compiled files which are send to browser"

*"bundleName"* : "is the name which you will find into **dist** folder"

3. According to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5880#issuecomment-292704434) answer you have to add into **index.html** the following **script** inside the **header** tag under the  `<base href="/">`

```html
          <script>
             window.onload = function () {
              function loadScript(scriptUrl) {
                const script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = scriptUrl;
                document.body.appendChild(script);
              }

              loadScript('font-awesome.js');
              loadScript('bootstrap.js');
            }

         </script>
```

**NOTE:** `window.onload = function ()` used to make sure that the page is loaded (this because our files into the **dist** are in **.js** format; this is the quick way for Angular to compile)

4. Run this command, to compile the application

```
    ng build --extract-css=false --prod
```

**NOTE:** on build we use *--extract-css=false* to generate **.js** files

*Testing*

- Go into the browser and change it to dev (F12 or right click and inspect element)
- Select Network tab
- Press Ctrl+Shift+R for hard reload

You must be able to see that the bootstrap.js and font-awesome.js are loaded separately like in the photo and also you be able to see for a moment the page without style => this is the moment when the style is loaded well after the DOM is loaded

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since I can't comment the accepted answer, I'll provide an important note to it as a separate one. Please move it there and delete from here if needed. So, the accepted answer is based on separate CSS file. Since Angular 6 you [can't](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10532#issuecomment-385712721) use neither `--extract-css` or `-ec` flags in `package.json` for `ng serve`, nor `extractCss: true` in `angular.json` for `serve` config section. Though, you can use [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10666#issuecomment-386843570) approach to make it work. Then you can load your lazy style by using [this](https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/lazy-loading-scripts-and-styles-angular/) approach with promise on `APP_INITIALIZER`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who want to use global css scipts in .angular-cli.json lazy loaded without hash I wrote following script (e.g. patch-ng-cli.js)

```
const fs = require('fs');

const stylesFileToPatch = "node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/styles.js";

const regex = /extraPlugins\.push\(.*\}\)\)\;/;
const patchContent = `
        // PATCHED CONTENT START
        const globalStyles = utils_1.extraEntryParser(appConfig.styles, appRoot, 'styles');
        extraPlugins.push(new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: getPath => {
            const generatedFileName = getPath(\`[name]\${hashFormat.extract}.bundle.css\`);
            const name = generatedFileName.split(".")[0];
            const globalAppStylesConfigEntry = globalStyles.find(path => path.output === name);
            if (globalAppStylesConfigEntry && globalAppStylesConfigEntry.lazy){
                console.log(\`\${name} will not be hashed due to lazy loading\`);
                return \`\${name}.bundle.css\`
            }
            console.log(generatedFileName);
            return generatedFileName;
        }}));
        // PATCHED CONTENT END
`;


fs.readFile(stylesFileToPatch, (err, data) => {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    const text = data.toString();

    const isAlreadyPatched = !!text.match("PATCHED CONTENT");

    if (isAlreadyPatched) return console.warn("-- already patched --", stylesFileToPatch);

    console.log('-- Patching ng-cli: ', stylesFileToPatch);
    const patchedContent = text.replace(regex, patchContent);

    const file = fs.openSync(stylesFileToPatch, 'r+');
    fs.writeFile(file, patchedContent, () => console.log("-- Patching -- OK"));
    fs.close(file);
});
```

Then run this script after npm install via npm scripts in package.json

```
"postinstall": "node ./patch-ng-cli.js",
```