# angular 4 multiple global styles with lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am building an angular 4 application with **angular-cli version 1.3.2** so far so good. I read in documentation that we can use global style with lazy loading at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles.

Now when I run the command

```
ng build --prod -vc -nc --build-optimizer
```

it generates following output for bootstrap

> chunk {bootstrapBundle}
>   bootstrapBundle.cf320d25069acd157990.bundle.css (bootstrapBundle) 96.9
>   kB {inline} [initial]

As per my understanding this css should be applied to the website but, when I see the website it doesn't have any bootstrap css applied on it.

Now, how can I use bootstrapBundle or bootstrap chunk in the site ?

Here is my **angular-cli.json** style configuration

```
"styles": [
      "styles.scss"
       {
         "input": "./assets/smartadmin/bootstrap.scss",
         "lazy": true,
         "output":"bootstrapBundle"
       },
    ],
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look in to [Lazy load application theme styles with Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152593/lazy-load-application-theme-styles-with-angular-cli) I think it should answer your question

Comment: @Kuncevic thanks for the link. I had also solved it in same way. I will add my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a solution to my problem with help of @Kuncevic who pointed me to this

> [Lazy load application theme styles with Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152593/lazy-load-application-theme-styles-with-angular-cli)

Now until this point the css files will be generated and if we add them to index.html via

```
<link href='yourstyle.bundle.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

then it will be eagerly loaded on first request.

***But the Problem Is, I really want to lazily load them and apply them over my website***

---

#### Solution.

1. Extracted css as mentioned in the article
2. Added style references to **app.component.html** since this will be a root component therefore I added it in this.

> **app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="stylesLoaded">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.cf320d25069acd157990.bundle.css">
</div>
```

3. Added **stylesLoaded** property to **app.component.ts**
4. Implemented **AfterViewChecked** in **app.component.ts**. For details [Check Life cycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

> **app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  stylesLoaded: boolean = false;
  
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.stylesLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

Now once your view is rendered the **AfterViewChecked** will be fired and makes the **stylesLoaded** to **true** this will enable the styles link in **app.component.html** and start loading them.

> **Hence lazy loaded :)**

In similar way you can load JS module(s).

Hope that will help someone. Happy coding

Comment: How could it works since you add the css bundle with the hash as a link in your index file ? Each time the app build, the hash change, then your link will be false and the bundle fetch will be the old one.

Comment: Extracted CSS bundles are no longer hashed in newer versions of Angular (definitely v10).