# Lazy loading styles in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to have `print-styles.scss` compiled in css and put into `assets` folder by angular compiler.

I need it for injecting styles into an iframe that should print some contents.

The problem is that in angular.json

```
styles: [{
   "input": "projects/public/src/print-styles.scss",
   "lazy": true,
   "bundleName": "print-styles-hello"
}]
```

results in JS file which I don't know how to use.

I don't want to use any Gulp or other additional tools.

Comment: Can you check this blog may be this will help:https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/lazy-loading-scripts-and-styles-angular/

Comment: @Chellappan I saw it but how can I guess the URL which I have to use? Angular compiles 2 bundles and prefixes them with hashes and targets. Also I don't see any changes on a page.

Comment: Check this also :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152593/lazy-load-application-theme-styles-with-angular-cli?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by specifying `"extractCss": true` which results in a constant expected `.css` output.